# Why does VBA macro stop on active cell change?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been away for 7 years from writing VBA and today I have been asked to do a simple thing and it doesn't work

I am trying to take the contents of 52 weekly summaries and put them all into one sheet:

So I can go to the first sheet - copy the data I need - go to the summary sheet - paste the data - and then it stops ... same if I just change the value of a cell - it changes the value and then stops.

Am I missing a security setting or something?

Here is the VBA

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

' Take cell contents of active sheet and paste into summary sheet

Sheets("we 03 Jan").Select
Do
    shtName = ActiveSheet.Name
    Range("A10:U39").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Full Year").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = shtName
    ' stops here
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
     False, Transpose:=False
    ' stops here if previous line causing stop is removed 
    Sheets(shtName).Select
    If ActiveSheet.Index = Worksheets.Count Then
        Worksheets(1).Select
        Exit Sub
        Else
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
        End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd guess you have some event code that is running in response to your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim n                     As Long
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo clean_up

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Sheets("we 03 Jan").Select
    For n = ActiveSheet.Index To Sheets.Count
        Set ws = Sheets(n)
        ws.Range("A10:U39").Copy

        With Sheets("Full Year").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Value = ws.Name
            .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                       SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With
    Next n

clean_up:
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Makes me realise how much I have missed out on in the last 7 years. Yes it does - thank you so much